# Is there a simple fill polygon tool in Maya like there is in blender?

Tags: maya

I'm just moving from Blender to Maya, and have spent the last few hours trying to find a Maya equivalent to the blender fill tool. The fill tool works in the blender by selecting at least two vertices and pressing the F key to make an edge connecting the two vertices, or if you have three or more vertices it will create a face connecting your selected vertices. I've seen the Maya fill-hole tool and the Maya append to polygon tool but neither seems to work when performing in as simple a way. If any of you could help me figure out what Maya users do to accomplish this, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: wrong place to ask honestly

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I would suggest you probably ask this on Blender Stack Exchange, but it's not a Blender question as such, and may be considered off-topic there.  Perhaps ask in their chat rooms first.  Blender and other 3D modelling software is really quite a specialist area of expertise.